# how to export flask restplus swagger json?

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restplus

i am trying to export a my flask restplus json format to a text file .txt
i check this documentation 
https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.0/export.html

```
No handlers could be found for logger "flask_restplus.api"
{u'error': u'Unable to render schema'}
```

but i get the error above,  i am doing something wrong? or should i have something set up?

my code is very simple

```
from flask import json
from my_appication import api
print api.__schema__
```

Answer (score 4):

found this in another place but tought my be worthy to have it here as well.

```
import os
import json
from my_appication import api
from my_appication import app

app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = "localhost"
app.app_context().__enter__()
print(json.dumps(api.__schema__, indent=2))
```

Comment: After several days of searching for various combinations of flask, restplus, swagger, documentation extractor...this was the solution! Nice and simple, thank you!